# How not to have 'version=GBmaster' in Azure DevOps links

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps urls to files and to wiki entries contain `&version=GBmaster` and `&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster` respectively.

Is it possible to configure DevOps not to append it?

Today I get:

- https://myorg.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyRepo?path=%2Fsrc%2FMyFile.cs&version=GBmaster
- https://dev.azure.com/rbtech/Redback/_wiki/wikis/MyOrg.wiki?pagePath=%2MyPage&pageId=204&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster

I wish for:

- https://myorg.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyRepo?path=%2Fsrc%2FMyFile.cs
- https://dev.azure.com/rbtech/Redback/_wiki/wikis/MyOrg.wiki?pagePath=%2MyPage&pageId=204

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of AzureDevop basically `&version/ &wikiversion` is denoted **which branch** the `code/wiki` is showing in the UI. Even if you don't provide the Version AzureDevOps will automatically append it to indicate which branch is chosen.

Let's say in your repo you have multiple branches means like `master`/ `develop` then based on the branch you choose the `&version` will change automatically like `&version=GBmaster` or `&version=GBdevelop` if you don't provide the default branch will be appended in the query.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it possible to configure DevOps not to append it?

No, there isn't a way to configure it. It's the expected behavior as Jayendran described, it's a tag which marks the file version from which branch.

If you want to see the contents of the files without the `&version=GBmaster`, then you can try call the REST API : [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

For example:

```
https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/{Project}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repository ID}/items?path=WAP/WAP.Tests/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
```